# Save the sent mail to a drive in ".msg" format

Tags: perl

I am trying to save all the mails sent from my outlook to a particular folder. This is the code I tried.

```
use Mail::Outlook;
my $outlook = new Mail::Outlook();
my $outlook = new Mail::Outlook('Sent Items');
my $folder = $outlook->folder();
my $folder = $outlook->folder('Sent Items');
$message = $folder->first();
$text = $message->Subject();
$test=$message->{message}->SaveAs("C:\\mail\\$text.msg");
print $text;
```

The above code would save one mail. how can I loop through all the sent mail and save it as ".msg" file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do that:

```
while (my $message = $folder->next()) {
    my $text = $message->Subject();
    my $test = $message->{message}->SaveAs("C:\\mail\\$text.msg");
}
```

Iterate as long as messages are in folder.

Comment: how to setwarnings to False?

Comment: @Programmer what is setwarning?

Comment: each time it loops, outlook prompts "an external prgm is accessing your details do u want to allow or deny?" how can I stop getting that kinda prompts

Comment: look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/i-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-e-mail-address-information-or-sending-e-mail-on-my-behalf-HA001229943.aspx). It is an option in outlook setup.